# You play the Nintendo Switch? Or you play to the Nintendo Switch?

Tags: prepositions

When you play a game on a videoconsole, do you "play the console" or "play to the console"?

Comment: You *play* a game *on* a console. You never play "to" the console.

Comment: Xavi, that seems to belong not here but on English Language Learners.

Even there, could you expound on why you Asked that?

The useful Question is what made you think either "play the console" or "play to the console" might be correct? Where did you get that idea?

Both are readily understood and both are also clearly wrong.

As Robusto said, you play a game on a console and that's all there is to it.

Comment: Well... first of all, thanks for your clarifications. Second, I'm Spanish/Catalan. I didn't know about the "English Language Learners" site and I have consulted a lot of times this one which made me think this was a good place to ask. I always thought this was a place for Q&A about "correct English usage" as its "tour" says: " Word choice and usage + Grammar" among others.

Comment: Having said that, the "to" comes from my mother languages: In both Spanish and Catalan, you say "Jugar *a* la consola". That pushed me towards the "to" preposition, as "a" = "to". But inctuitively it seemed rather weird to me in English. It sounded like "hard". This is why I thought I might have to leave the "to" out somehow. This is the reason why I asked that.

Comment: Moreover I'm creating an altruist free site for the confined kids of the world during those coronavirus times in multiple languages - ex: Catalan here http://www.coronamaze.org/ca/ and English here: http://www.coronamaze.org/en/ - I'm creating puzzles for the kids and I am also doing the translation into English by myself until I encounter some altruist (native) soul that wants to help me with that. In the meanwhile, the second puzzle was entitled in Catalan "Jugant *a* la Nintendo Switch" and the doubt arised when I was generating the puzzles for the English speaking kids.

Comment: I finally dropped the "to" in the title... and in the text it says "Since Laura is getting bored by the lockdown, she plays *with* the Nintendo Switch every day for a while." which I guess I need to mutate to "Since Laura is getting bored by the lockdown, she plays *on* the Nintendo Switch every day for a while.". Am I right?